# converting the thumbnile image into original size

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, image-manipulation, thumbnails

i am converting the image into thumbnail format and sending it to server  and i want to convert it back to original size while receiving can any one please tell me how to resize the image to original without loosing quality.....

i tried directly to displaying the image in image view but the quality of the image is missing ...
can any one please help me how to maintain the quality of the image .......

Comment: -1, you will have serious difficulties with programming, if you haven't heard of pixels before. If you have heard, then you will have even more difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible. You can't enlarge an image while maintaining the same quality. If you think about an image as a mapped array of pixels (literally, a "bit-map"), this makes sense. The image is saved with a fixed amount of data, and that's all you have to work with when you resize it. Any examples to the contrary (like TV shows) are purely fictional.

Investigate using **[vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)** instead, which can be resized at will without a loss of quality.

Answer (score 2):

Downscaling is irreversible, some information lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

you simply can not convert an image from thumbnail to original size and retain the quality it had in its original size.

if you want to display the image full-size, you have to send the full-size image.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about using a Vector image? They do not lose quality when resized. But I have no clue whether you can use them for thumbnails in iOS.

See [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) for more info about Vector graphics.